# How can I parallelise this nested for loop in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

I have a numpy 2D array and I need to call a function on all of its elements.

The way I am doing it now is:

```
h, w, c = x.shape
for i in range( 0, h ):
    for j in range( 0, w ):
        my_func( x[i][j][0], x[i][j][1], x[i][j][2] )
```

`my_func()` is a function that determines the nearest colour to the pixels from `x`, whose R, G and B values are `x[i][j][0]`, `x[i][j][1]` and `x[i][j][2]` at any position `[i,j]`.

I am still learning about parallel programming in Python. What is the recommended way to call this function in parallel on different elements of the array `x`?

I am also exploring the way of wrapping this up in Tensorflow to be able to run it on the GPU.

Comment: You could vectorize it and call functions on them.

Comment: What does `my_func` do?

Comment: @user1767754 note, vectorization is not the same as parallelization.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga read your comment... that's true, removed my answer. I thought that vectorized will run always parallel?

Comment: @user1767754 `vectorized` will run a python `for` loop. It's slow, compared to a vectorized operation in numpy. It's important to know what the OP currently does via that function.

Comment: @user1767754 no, vectorization is not equivalent to parallelization. There are some `numpy`/`scipy` functions that *do get parallelized*, e.g. a lot of BLAS functions, but that also depends on your BLAS library, and how it was compiled. Furthermore, the `np.vectorized` function doesn't give you the performance benefits of the built-in `numpy.ufuncs`, which are vectorized, but that performance comes from being written as C-extensions. `np.vectorize` let's you use a fucntion in the same way, e.g. taking advantage of broadcasting behavior, but without those benefits.

Comment: @roganjosh edited my question. thanks !

Comment: Is `my_func` massive? If not, it would be helpful to include it because I'm still not sure how this should function from your edit.